# How to configure android studio to build api 22 app

Tags: api, kotlin, build, sdk, configure

I need to install my app in a Minix with Android 5.1 (API 22).

My build-graddle.app was initially:

compileSdk 32

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.enterprise.appminix"
    minSdk 25
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

And I changed to:

compileSdk 22

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.enterprise.appminix"
    minSdk 22
    targetSdk 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

But can´t compile now.

How to configure android studio to build api 22 app

Could you help me?

Comment: How to configure android studio to build api 22 app

Comment: You don't need to change the target Sdk or the tools version to compile the app so it will install on an older API.

Comment: It does not function.

Comment: It would help to know what the error message is.

Comment: ¿How to configure these parameters in android studio to build api 22 app:  compileSdk, minSdk and targetSdk?

Comment: compileSdkVersion should be whatever the latest SDK is you have installed in Android Studio. If you were using 32, keep it as 32. minsdkVersion should be set to 22. targetSdkVersion can be anything between 22 and 32. If you are compiling only for an API 22, device, I would keep targetSdkVersion at 22 for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you, Tenfour04.

I did as you suggest. The app compiled and could be installed on the Minix device with Lollipop, but when I try to run it, it doesn't load. It briefly shows a black screen and closes.

And I tried to compile by changing compileSDK to 22, but it can't. Many application dependencies fail.

Comment: There could be a million reasons for that. Can't help without a detailed description of the dependencies used and a stacktrace of your crash. If you're new to programming with Android, you need to first learn how to debug stack traces so you can narrow down your problems before you come here for help. Otherwise, there's nothing we can do to help you solve it.

Comment: You're right.

Thank you very much, Tenfour04.